# "Universal Android App" (template) news mobile app, list not working

Tags: json, wordpress, android-studio, config.json

sorry for bothering you. I need help with this template:
https://codecanyon.net/item/universal-full-multipurpose-android-app/6512720

I would like to insert my website (in Altervista, www.umbertoprimo.altervista.org) listing the news, but I have a problem.

What is written in the documentation:

*If you would like to show the latest WordPress posts or a category in your app, you can add a WordPress item to the menu. We have installed our API plugin as documented earlier. Now follow the instructions depending on if you are using the JSON API or the JetPack / WordPress.com API.*

> JSON API You can use the following values for your configuration: The
>   first parameter is the url to your WordPress blog (starting with
>   http:// and not ending with a slash). The second parameter is a
>   category slug (which you can leave empty for all posts combined). The
>   last and third parameter is optional, and this is a Disqus formatted
>   string.

I installed the JSON API in the website with Wordpress but... this is what I came with.

```
[
  {
    "title":"Inter Nos",
    "drawable":"",
    "submenu":"",
    "iap":false,
    "tabs":[
      {
        "title":"Post Recenti",
        "provider":"wordpress",
        "arguments":[
          "http://umbertoprimo.altervista.org"
        ]
      },
      {
        "title":"Numeri Interi",
        "provider":"wordpress",
        "arguments":[
          "org.altervista.umberto",
          "numeri-interi"
        ]
      },
      {
        "title":"Contatti",
        "provider":"wordpress",
        "arguments":[
          "en.blog.wordpress.com",
          "security"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

(config.json, using Android Studio)

And the "Contatti" table works, showing all the news from the "blog.wordpress", but the recent posts and numeri-interi don't. 
I tried using as provider "altervista", but nothing.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance, this is just a test as part of my app.

P.S. When I build the app, no problem, but when I open it... [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j5qK.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAjL3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Jetpack for you to use that option because the Api's are different. The "Post Recenti" works because you have the Json Api installed, the "Contatti" works beacause wordpress has the Jetpack plugin installed and its contains the wordpress resp api.